# Binding a Pivot to a Dictionary

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to build a `Pivot` system based on some collections, without having to build it using code-behind.

My collection is a `Dictionary<CategoriesEnum, List<object>>` and I'd like to bind the `PivotItem`'s header to the `CategoriesEnum` object, while its content has to be bound to the related `List<objet>`.

Actually I've been able to just bind the `PivotItem`'s header but I really can't do it for the `List`.
Here's my current code:

(XAML)

```
        <phone:Pivot x:Name="pivot"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}">
            <phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <phone:PivotItem Header="{Binding}">
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Objects}">
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </phone:PivotItem>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:Pivot>
```

(C#)

```
public List<Categories> Categories
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<Categories>(Dictionary.Keys);
        }
    }

    public List<object> Objects
    {
        get
        {
            return Dictionary[(Categories)pivot.SelectedItem];
        }
    }
```

I know that the `Objects` property will never work this way, but I can't figure out how to do this type of binding and I've not found anything online to give me a clue.

Comment: Is the list created and filled with data before you do the binding? Do you get any binding errors listed?

Comment: you can use converter to get the data

Comment: No binding errors, and the list is filled! @techloverr: I'll try it asap because it sounds a nice idea

Comment: @techloverr: I've added a `Converter` to the `ListBox`'s `ItemsSource` but the `Converter` is never called

Comment: Since it's a dictionary, I think you want to bind to the 'Value' property.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample?

Comment: how you binded can you share?

Answer (score 0):

Binding the ItemsSource to a dictionary enumerates the KeyValuePairs, from which you can bind to the Key and Value properties. Let's assume the Keys in your dictionary are string and the Values are enumerables (IList):
(XAML)

```
    <phone:Pivot x:Name="pivot" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDictionary}">
        <phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <phone:PivotItem Header="{Binding Key}">
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Value}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyName}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </phone:PivotItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    </phone:Pivot>
```

(C#)

```
public IDictionary<string, IList<MyObject>> MyDictionary { get; set; }
public class MyObject 
{ 
     public string MyName { get; set; }
}
```